# > Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output

[image]

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools menu > SDK Manager and under SDK Tools page, select '30.0.3' under the Android SDK Build-Tools and Apply and OK.

Then gradle sync after download is successful.